# How to display the div with content in a vbhtml using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display content in a div inside a popover using Javascript and facing some issue. Below is the code. Hope someone can help..

1) ASP.Net master page that calls the pop up vbhtml page

```
 window.izenda=false;
                $("#NextGenReportsLink").click(function(){
                    if(!window.izenda)
                    {
                        PleaseWaitOpen();
                        window.izenda=true;
                       $.get("/Report/NextGenReportViewer", function(data){ 
                            $("#NextGenReportSelectorNew").append(data)
                        });
                    }
                });
```

2) The vbhtml page that should pop up on click of #NextGenReportsLink

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
      <link href="~/Scripts/EmbeddedUI/izenda-ui.css?db1ebd9b10aa86f1fd76" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="~/Content/ReportsFiles/Css/jquery.webui-popover.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/ReportsFiles/Css/nanoscroller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/ReportsFiles/Css/reports.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

    <script src="~/Content/ReportsFiles/Js/jquery.webui-popover.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/ReportsFiles/Js/jquery.nanoscroller.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="row" id="data" >
        <div class="container" id="izenda-root"></div>   
        </div>  


    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/EmbeddedUI/izenda_common.js?db1ebd9b10aa86f1fd76"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/EmbeddedUI/izenda_locales.js?db1ebd9b10aa86f1fd76"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/EmbeddedUI/izenda_vendors.js?db1ebd9b10aa86f1fd76"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/EmbeddedUI/izenda_ui.js?db1ebd9b10aa86f1fd76"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/izenda.integrate.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             debugger;

             //$("#NextGenReportsLink").click();
             PleaseWaitClose();
             DoIzendaConfig();
             izendaInit();
             document.getElementById('NextGenReportSelectorNew').style.display = "block";


             var Wid = $(window).width();
             var Hei = $(window).height() - (38 + 85);

             var Per98 = parseInt(98 / 100 * Wid)
             var Per1 = parseInt((Wid - Per98) / 2);
             var options = {
                 valueNames: ['name']
             };

             $('#NextGenReportsLink').webuiPopover({

                 placement: 'vertical',
                 trigger: 'click',
                 width: Per98,
                 offsetTop: -10,
                 height: Hei,
                 arrow: true,
                 title: 'NextGenReports',
                 closeable: true,
                 animation: 'fade',
                 onHide: function () { $("#loadingDiv").hide(); },
                 onShow: function () {
                     var Wid = $(window).width();
                     var Hei = $(window).height() - (38 + 85);

                     var Per98 = parseInt(98 / 100 * Wid)
                     var Per1 = parseInt((Wid - Per98) / 2);
                     $('.webui-popover.fade').css('left', Per1);
                     var ll = $('#NextGenReportsLink').offset().left + ($('#NextGenReportsLink').width() / 2)
                     $('.webui-arrow').css('left', (ll - Per1) + 10);
                 },
                 content: $('#data').html(),
                 type: 'html'
             });



             $(window).resize(function () {

                 debugger;
                 if ($('.webui-popover').is(':visible')) {


                     var Wid = $(window).width();
                     var Hei = $(window).height() - (38 + 85);

                     var Per98 = parseInt(98 / 100 * Wid)
                     var Per1 = parseInt((Wid - Per98) / 2);
                     var ll = $('#NextGenReportsLink').offset().left + ($('#NextGenReportsLink').width() / 2)
                     $('.webui-arrow').css('left', ll - Per1 + 9);
                 }
             })
        });

    </script>    

</body>
</html>
```

izendaInit(); function loads a UI into the izenda-root div, however that div is not getting displayed. Instead the below div is getting displayed

[image: The div being displayed while inspecting in the dev tools]

I can see another div with the same id "izenda-root" being loaded with the data but I'm not sure how to display that div. Any help is much appreciated.. Please let me know if you need any more documentation on the js/css files referred to in the vbhtml..

[image: The div that is getting loaded by the izendaInit() function]

3) Below is the izenda.integrate.js

```
//This function will point the front-end at an Izenda API
var DoIzendaConfig = function () {
    var configJson = {
        "WebApiUrl": "http://x.x.x.x:yy/api/",
        "BaseUrl": "/",
        "RootPath": "Scripts/EmbeddedUI",
        "CssFile": "izenda-ui.css",
        "Routes": {
            "Settings": "settings",
            "New": "new",
            "Dashboard": "dashboard",
            "Report": "report",
            "ReportViewer": "reportviewer",
            "ReportViewerPopup": "reportviewerpopup",
            "Viewer": "viewer"
        },
        "Timeout": 3600,
    };
    IzendaSynergy.config(configJson);
};


//Error checking during token generation
function errorFunc() {
    alert('Token was not generated correctly.');
}
//DoRender will called via successFunc
var DoRender = function (successFunc) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://xxxx.mock.pstmn.io/GenerateToken",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });
};



//The IzendaSynergy.render function will render the entire Izenda front-end with an independent navigation
var izendaInit = function () {
    function successFunc(data, status) {
        var currentUserContext = {
            token: data.token
        };
        IzendaSynergy.setCurrentUserContext(currentUserContext);
        IzendaSynergy.render(document.getElementById('izenda-root'));
    }
    this.DoRender(successFunc);
};
```

Comment: Please show contents of `izendaInit()` method. Possibly you're using wrong selector when trying to load contents inside `<section>` tag.

Comment: The body of izendaInit() method is towards the end of the last snippet in my question (izenda.integrate.js).. Thank you for responding..